# Unable to save uploaded file to filesystem with SF2

Tags: php, image, forms, symfony, filesystems

I am trying to handle a file that is being uploaded via a form and save it to my file system. However, when I do I always get an error along these lines from `Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.php`

`Unable to create the "/images/gallery" directory 
500 Internal Server Error - FileException`

In my controller I have this code, which handles form validation, entity persistence etc.

```
$gallery_image = new GalleryImage();
$form          = $this->createForm(new GalleryImageType(), $gallery_image);

// Bind the posted data to the form
$form->bind($this->getRequest());
// Make sure the form is valid before we persist the image
if ($form->isValid()) {
   // Get the entity manager and persist the contact
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

   $gallery_image->upload();

   $em->persist($gallery_image);
   $em->flush();

   // etc...         
}
```

In the `upload` method I am doing this:

`$this->image->move('/images/gallery', 'test.'.$this->image->guessExtension());`

So my intention was to move it to `/web/images/gallery`.

I have tried changing `/web` to `777`, so the problem does not appear to be a permissions issue.

Is `/web/images/gallery` the correct place to put these images and is there any reason why I am unable to save this file to the file system?

Comment: What does your server's error log show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your code you mean the root of your drive. So the path to your web folder is not correct.

Try something more like that :

```
$this->image->move(__DIR__ . '/../../../../web/images/gallery', 'test.'.$this->image->guessExtension());
```

It should work if you have created images and gallery folder in your web directory.

Ref : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

Comment: To shorten the code you may use this as well `$this->image->move($this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../web/images/gallery/', 'test.'.$this->image->guessExtension());`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was indeed something as simple as an invalid path. I read that page in the cookbook, but i'll go and have another read at that section specifically.